# Enable fields and allow editing with keyup value

Tags: javascript

I have a script the enables/disables a text field when a value is entered in another field. The problem is when the field becomes enabled I also want it to be editable. The current script enables the field but I cannot edit the text. Here's what I have

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
 $('.addbut').onkeyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
           $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {

           $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
      }
 });
});
</script>
```

Then the html form has this.

```
<div class="input ">
<input type="text"  class="addbut" name="location" id="location"></div>


<div class="input"><input class="enableOnInput" disabled=""type="text"id="name" name="street" required></div>
```

Comment: If it is enabled, then you can edit it. Right?

Comment: @iSITKiosk That was not a nice thing to do... create question, get good answer, totally change question, and then delete the entire post...

Comment: Sorry yezzz. The previous question and answer didn't work. I had to modify the code so it didn't apply to my situation. I didn't want to waste other peoples time to answer a question that wasn't relevant.

Comment: Well, it was a valid question and a working answer. Would have been better to leave that page alone for others to see, and start a new question, the latter of which you did here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.keyup(` instead of `.onkeyup(`

Comment: Wow. Thank for you that. I can't believe that worked.